# Why do I see an empty array returned from my laravel relationship model

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent

I have 2 model, SurveyQuestion and SurveyQuestionOption

**SurveyQuestionOption Model**

```
public function opinions(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\SurveyOpinions','option_id');
}
```

**SurveyQuestion Model**

```
public function options(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\SurveyQuestionOption','question_id');
}
```

**Controller**

```
public function getQuestions(){

    $data=SurveyQuestion::with('options')
                          ->get();
    
    if(count($data)>0)
    {
        return api::success(['data' => $data]);
    }

    return api::notFound(['errorMsg' => 'No Survey initiated yet!!!']);                           
}
```

When I hit get Question Api am getting an empty array from the model. I tried that by putting dd() for the `$data` Variable.

Comment: can you check what `SurveyQuestion::all()` is returning?

Comment: The response is still an empty array.

Comment: so it means there is no record on database

Comment: I have 2 questions and 2 options for each question. question_id is used as a Foreign key in the options table. That's the thing freaking me out, how this happening :(

Comment: Please check if you are connected to the correct database and it has those records which you mentioned above.

Comment: I Created 2 new models and copies the same code, and it worked :). I still don't get what's the exact error, but it worked now. Thanks For your Efforts.